# How handle a Tag field in JS together with Flask Form?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Intro: I can receive the values from input fields in Flask by

```
var = request.form['description']
```

and the following HTML:

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="description">Beschreibung</label>
            <textarea name="description" placeholder="Post description"
                      class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Question: Any idea how to handle a tag field, like e.g. [Link](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/tags-input-box-html-javascript/) , together with Flask Form? How to handle Flask Form and $.Ajax Post request simultaneously? Any hint would be highly appriciated. I did my research but found nothing online.

Comment: AJAX POST works exactly like a normal POST, to flask, it makes no difference where the data is sent from. If by using both simultaneously, you mean having a common endpoint that receives the data, then yes..

Answer (score 0):

I found now an easy solution for me. Don´t know if it is very clean but what I did was basically create a hidden field and pass the var from JS to the hidden field inside <form so that i can grab it with request in Flask. I also did this the other way around, passing the variable from Flask to JS. In this way I can use the CSS,JS in the link above outside of <form, i.e. I can press Enter

HTML:

```
<!-- from JS to Flask -->
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_tags" id="hidden_tags" value="" />
<!-- from Flask to JS -->
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_tags2" id="hidden_tags2" value="{{ post['tags'] }}"/>
```

in JS:

```
tags = document.getElementById("hidden_tags2").value.split('/');
document.getElementById("hidden_tags").value  = tags
```

in Flask:
`request.form['hidden_tags']`